# Dev visible in app_dev.php but not visible in app.php

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I work on an app in symfony 2 which uses the sonata-admin bundle.
I added 6 vars in my entity, and I can edit their value in my back-office to see the result in the front office.

Everything works fine when I go to my website in app_dev.php (and app_dev.php/admin for the back office)

But when I try to access to the website within the app.php, the changes don't show in my front office and I have a 404 error in the back.
If I explicite the vars's typos in the $formMapper of the sonata admin's configureFormFields function, I can see my form but it doesn't get back the values already stored in the database.

I must precise I tried all clear cache options possible, with --env, --no-debug, and I tried to delete the app/cache/prod folder, create it again with the permissions. Apache logs do not show anything in particular.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What about symfony's logs in `app/logs`?

Comment: What @DiegoFerri said. Always, always check the logs :) This filters out most unwanted logging noise: `tail -f app/logs/prod.log | grep -v DEBUG`. Run that, reload the page. You should get some meaningful information from that.

Comment: My last significant log message concerns an old error already corrected. I do not have any more log for one hour, even if I refresh the page.

Please note that everything works fine, dev or prod on my local computer.

Comment: Okay, it's not actually clear from your question - but your comment suggests that you have no problem on your local machine in either environment, and you are only experiencing this issue on a production server. Is this accurate? If so, can you verify that the production server is fit for purpose? You can run `php app/check.php`, and browse to `http://yourdomain.com/config.php` which might confirm if there is a server-level issue.

Comment: I checked the `domain.com/config.php` and I saw the error : the timezone was not defined in my php.ini. I defined it and now everything is OK. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

try to clear cache with

```
 php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
```